# Python abundant, deficient, or perfect number

Tags: python, for-loop, indentation, break

```
def classify(numb):
    i=1
    j=1
    sum=0
    for i in range(numb):
        for j in range(numb):
            if (i*j==numb):
                sum=sum+i
                sum=sum+j
            if sum>numb:
                print("The value",numb,"is an abundant number.")
            elif sum<numb:
                print("The value",numb,"is a deficient number.")
            else:
                print("The value",numb,"is a perfect number.")
            break
    return "perfect"
```

The code takes a number(numb) and classifies it as an abundant, deficient or perfect number. My output is screwy and only works for certain numbers. I assume it's indentation or the break that I am using incorrectly. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific about what is your problem really is

Comment: I understand the problem but not your implementation, or where it's coming from, could you explain your code a bit?

Comment: i and j are the factors of the number if i*j==numb. Then and only then the factors are added to sum. When the for loop completes it compares the sum to the numb to determine if the numb is abundant, deficient, or perfect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number#Related_concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend u to create a one function which creates the proper divisor of given N, and after that, the job would be easy.

```
def get_divs(n):
    return [i for i in range(1, n) if n % i == 0]


def classify(num):
    divs_sum = sum(get_divs(num))
    if divs_sum > num:
        print('{} is abundant number'.format(num))
    elif divs_sum < num:
        print('{} is deficient number'.format(num))
    elif divs_sum == num:
        print('{} is perfect number'.format(num))
```

Comment: Why `< 2 * num`? I assume that's a typo.

Comment: Why not `< 2 * num`? "In number theory, a deficient or deficient number is a number n for which the sum of divisors σ(n)<2n [...]" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number)

Comment: That is because the last number added by the divisor function is the number you started with. So you should probably regard this in your other if statements. Or you could remove the plus 1 in get divs.

Comment: I thought the number itself is also a divisor of itself and therefore added to the sum. Example: "As an example, consider the number 21. Its divisors are 1, 3, 7 and 21, and their sum is 32. Because 32 is less than 2 × 21, the number 21 is deficient. Its deficiency is 2 × 21 − 32 = 10." (also Wikipedia)

Comment: Your thinking is corret but you are not correct. You are confusing different concepts. Either you keep with proper divisors or all divisors of a number. Your code as is are not correct.

Comment: Fixed - i think. I've made it `divs_sum - num < 2 * num` based on "A positive proper divisor is a positive divisor of a number n, excluding n "

Comment: Thank you, but.. You have just fixed it for deficient numbers, right?.. Don't mean to be winy, but right now all your numbers is abundant!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are misinterpreting something. As is you are printing what kind the number is, as many times as the value of the number. I might be missing something but anyway.

The sum of proper divisors can be found naively through using modulo

```
def classify1(num):
    div_sum = sum(x for x in range(1, num) if num % x == 0)
    kind = ""
    if div_sum < num:
        kind = "deficient"
    elif div_sum > num:
        kind = "abundant"
    else:
        kind = "perfect"
    print("{} is a {} number".format(num, kind))
```

---

but for big numbers or maybe numbers this will take a long time. So I welcome you to the divisor function. I just dump it and explain it.

```
def mark(li: list, x: int):

    for i in range(2*x, len(li), x):
        li[i] = False
    return li


def sieve(lim: int):
    li = [True] * lim
    li[0] = li[1] = 0
    for x in range(2, int(lim ** 0.5) + 1):
        if x:
            li = mark(li, x)
    return [2]+[x for x in range(3, lim, 2) if li[x]]


def factor(num):

    divs = list()
    for prime in primes:
        if prime * prime > num:
            if num > 1:
                divs += [num]
            return divs
        while num % prime == 0:
            num //= prime
            divs += [prime]
    else:
        return divs


def divisors_sum(num):
    """
    Function that implements a geometric series to generate the sum of the
     divisors, but it is not the divisor function since removing original
     number.
    """
    divs = factor(num)
    div_sum, s = 1, 0
    for div in set(divs):
        s = 0
        for exponent in range(0, divs.count(div) + 1):
            s += div ** exponent
        div_sum *= s
    else:
        return div_sum - num


primes = sieve(limit)
```

but.. there is not much explaining due, first prime factor the numbers, and use the divisor function to get the proper divisors sum. That is it. However the speed up is ridiculously much fast. This might seem to over kill the problem but it is just that much more cooler and faster.